# Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError in app using engine, nginx, passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nginx, passenger

I have an application which uses an engine (included by Gemfile  **gem my_engine, path=> '../my_engine'**). It works nice with **rails server**. I decided to move it to nginx with passenger, but I get an error.

> Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError
>
> ```
> auth_engine.css isn't precompiled
>
> Extracted source (around line #1):
>
> 1: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "auth_engine" %>
> 2: 
> 3: <div class="form">
> 4:   <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
> ```

**auth_engine.css** is located in my_engine/app/assets/stylesheets

How to fix this?

Comment: Ahhh... it was a typo. In this css file there was one additional invalid '.' character which prevented it from compiling but didn't show up in development env. Calling **rake assets:precompile --trace** from main app's dir revealed it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just linking to that one stylesheet separately instead of just letting rails roll into application.css. In that case, you should just move it to the public/assets/stylesheets folder to use it without compiling it.